# Hide Header Group Template in Kendo grid Export to excel

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I’m using a Kendo grid to display a list of details, like this:

```
<div style="text-align:left;position:relative;width:auto;width:99%;padding:4px;padding-top:0px;color:#286006"
     id="centerPane-IFrame">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<SDByBatchPublisherReportVM>()
        .Name("ReportGrid")
        .EnableCustomBinding(true)
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(x => x.PublisherName)
                .Title("Publisher")
                .Visible(true)
                .Width("50%")
                .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight: bold;" })
                .ClientGroupHeaderTemplate(
                    "Publisher: #=value# </td>" +
                    "<td style='text-align:center;'>Product Count: #=aggregates.ProductName.count# </td>" +
                    "<td>Discrepancy Count") //Discrepancy Count: #=aggregates.SDCount.sum#
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:left" })
                .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true).Search(true));
                
            columns.Bound(x => x.ProductName)
                .Title("Product")
                .Width("60%")
                .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight: bold;" })
                .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true).Search(true));
                
            columns.Bound(x => x.SDCount)
                .Title("Discrepancy Count")
                .Width("30%")
                .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight: bold;" })
                .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true).Search(true));
                
            columns.Template(@<text></text>).Title("").Width(1);                                                       
        })
        .Pageable(m => m.PageSizes(new int[] { 50, 100, 150, 500 }).Refresh(true))
        .Selectable(selectable => selectable
            .Enabled(true)
            .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single)
            .Type(GridSelectionType.Row)
        )
        .Scrollable()
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Batch(false)
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .PageSize(100)
            .Read(read => read
                .Action("ByBatchPublisherGrid_Read", "SoftwareDiscrepancyMetrics")
                .Data("buildReportData")
            )
            .Aggregates(agg =>
            {
                agg.Add(x => x.SDCount).Sum();
                agg.Add(x => x.ProductName).Count();
            })
            .Group(group =>
            {
                group.Add(x => x.PublisherName);
            })
        )
        .Events(evt => evt.DataBound("OnDataBound"))
        .Excel(excel => excel.AllPages(true).Filterable(true))
    )
</div>
```

I'm trying to export the grid data to Excel. My requirement is that I need to delete the `GroupHeaderTemplate` data when exporting to excel (there's no need to display that group header template data in excel).

This is the function I'm currently using:

```
 function ExportButtonClick() {
    debugger
    
    var grid = $("#ReportGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    if (grid.dataSource.total() == 0) {
        alert("There are no records available in the Grid to Export!!!");
    }
    else {
        var firstGroup = grid.dataSource.group()[0].field;
        $('#grid tbody .k-grouping-row:contains("")').hide();
        
        grid.bind("excelExport", function (e) {
            var batchId = $("#txtBatchId").data("kendoDropDownList").text();
            e.workbook.fileName = "By_BatchPublisher_Report_" + batchId + ".xlsx";
            debugger
            
            var sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];
            var rows = e.workbook.sheets[0].rows;
            var gridData = "";
            
            //This is for Remvoing HTML Tags from Cell text // added on 07-05-2018
            for (var ri = 0; ri < rows.length; ri++) {
                var row = rows[ri];

                for (var ci = 0; ci < row.cells.length; ci++) {
                    row.cells[ci].hidden = true;
                    var cell = row.cells[ci];
                   
                    if (row.type == "group-header") {
                        cell.value = "";
                    }
                        
                    if (cell.value) {
                        gridData = cell.value;
                        
                        if (!$.isNumeric(cell.value)) {
                            cell.value = gridData.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");
                        } else {
                            cell.value = gridData;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            //End Here
            debugger
            for (var i = 0; i < sheet.columns.length; i++) {
                sheet.columns[i].autoWidth = false;
                sheet.columns[i].width = 300;
            }
        });
        
        grid.saveAsExcel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can any one help me

Comment: Why no one helping me

Answer (score 1):

try this way:

```
function (e) {
            var rows = e.workbook.sheets[0].rows;
            var newRows = []
            for (var ri = 0; ri < rows.length; ri++) {
                var row = rows[ri];

                if (row.type !== "group-header") {
                    newRows.push(row)
                }
            }
            e.workbook.sheets[0].rows = newRows
            return e;
        }
```

There is nice similar examples in the last post here: https://www.telerik.com/forums/export-to-excel-also-exports-the-group-footer-template